# C#. Dictionary. Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#

```
            Dictionary<int, List<Car>> list = new Dictionary<int, List<Car>>();
            if (model.Distinct().Any())
            {
                foreach (var item in model)
                {
                    if (!list.ContainsKey(item.CompanyId))
                        list.Add(item.CompanyId, null);

                    if (list.ContainsKey(item.CompanyId))
                    {
                        var cars = model.Where(x => x.CompanyId == item.CompanyId).Select(x => x.Car);
                        list[item.CompanyId].AddRange(cars);
                    }
                        
                }
            }
```

Вышибает ошибку на `list[item.CompanyId].AddRange(cars);`

Сама `CompanyId = 4`, а `cars` получает необходимые записи из выборки.
В чем может быть проблема? Всё перепробовал, но с места так и не сдвинулся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавляете в словарь `null`, после этого `.AddRange(cars)` от `null` выдаёт ошибку. Добавляйте в словарь новый список:

```
if (!list.ContainsKey(item.CompanyId))
  list.Add(item.CompanyId, new List<Car>());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Думаю вы правы. Завтра утром обязательно проверю.